# From where I can get Cloud data for free for production process?

Tags: maps, real-time, weather, satellite

I am working on a map service and I want to add a new feature to showcase real-time data from clouds. So I want to know a service which provides the data for free.

I tried EUMESTAT as a data provider service but I cannot find how to retrieve the data from it.

Comment: A Google search can show you options. To get data from EUMESTAT you need to access their API, or use someone other API so you can gather data. https://www.tomorrow.io/weather-api/